# How to summarize text-strings with ddply?

Tags: regex, string, r, plyr

I want to summarize a text-variable of my data. For now I have this kind of code in mind, but don't know which code I need for summarizing the text variable.

```
dat <- ddply(df, .(user), summarise, links = as.numeric(length(user)),
               group = as.factor(substr(user,1,3)),
               classif = # some code for creating a string of the variabel "classifications", 
               unique.classif = # some code for creating a numeric variable of the unique occurences for the variabel "classifications"
               )
```

I probably need some regular expressions, but have no experience with that. Any suggestions?

`classif` for user `fxf20` should be something like: `"voeding","ziekte","sociale aspecten","erfelijkheid","ziekte","beweging"`

`unique.classif` should in this case produce the number `5` (there are six classifications, but "ziekte" is used twice)

```
df <- structure(list(user = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("frt01", "frt02", "frt03", "frt04", "frt05", 
"frt06"), class = "factor"), url = structure(c(3L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 
6L, 8L, 7L, 14L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 14L, 
12L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 3L, 10L, 
9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 4L), .Label = c("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57047/google2.html", 
"http://mens-en-gezondheid.infonu.nl/ziekten/18079-risicos-van-overgewicht-en-de-gevolgen-van-obesitas.html", 
"http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obesitas", "http://www.erfelijkheid.nl/node/325", 
"http://www.hely.net/oorzaken.html", "http://www.nisb.nl/kennisplein-sport-bewegen/dossiers/bewegen-en-overgewicht/oorzaken-obesitas.html", 
"http://www.novarum.nl/eetproblemen/obesitas/signalen-en-gevolgen", 
"http://www.obesitas.azdamiaan.be/nl/index.aspx?n=280", "http://www.obesitaskliniek.nl/over-obesitas/", 
"http://www.obesitasvereniging.nl/", "http://www.sagbmaagband.nl/minder-gewicht/morbideobesitas.html", 
"http://www.tweestedenziekenhuis.nl/script/Template_SubsubMenu.asp?PageID=1144&SSMID=1247", 
"http://www.vgz.nl/zorg-en-gezondheid/ziektes-en-aandoeningen/obesitas", 
"http://www.zuivelengezondheid.nl/?pageID=332"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(4L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 5L, 
    7L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("20-04-2012 10:10:00", "20-04-2012 9:09:37", 
    "20-04-2012 9:09:42", "20-04-2012 9:09:43", "20-04-2012 9:09:44", 
    "20-04-2012 9:09:45", "20-04-2012 9:09:46", "20-04-2012 9:09:47", 
    "20-04-2012 9:09:48", "20-04-2012 9:09:49", "20-04-2012 9:09:50", 
    "20-04-2012 9:09:52", "20-04-2012 9:09:54", "20-04-2012 9:09:55", 
    "20-04-2012 9:09:56", "20-04-2012 9:09:57", "20-04-2012 9:09:59"
    ), class = "factor"), classifications = structure(c(23L, 
    22L, 17L, 1L, 19L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 15L, 14L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 6L, 16L), .Label = c(";", 
    "1;2;", "2watishetprecies;1hoekrijgtiemandhet;", "3gevolgen;", 
    "3gevolgen;2watishetprecies;", "gevolg;sterfte;ziekte;", 
    "gevolgen;", "hoekrijgjeobesitas;", "obesitas;", "obesitas;opdracht;", 
    "obestitas;", "obestitas;gevolgen;", "obestitas;hoekrijgjeobesitas;gevolgen;", 
    "ontstaan;risicos;overgewicht;", "oorzaak;oorzaken;gevolg;", 
    "oorzaak;ziekte;type;", "oorzaken;", "oorzaken;bmi;overgewicht;", 
    "opdracht;obesitas;", "signalen;gevolg;", "wanneer;bmi;", 
    "watisobesitas;gevolgen;", "watisobesitas;oorzaken;"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("user", 
"url", "date", "classifications"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

---

I tested the solution of @SvenHohenstein, but that is not working exactly as intended. For some users I get the correct output, but for some others I don't. Output for a user were not the correct output is given: `12;,3gevolgen,2watishetprecies1hoekrijgtiemandhet;,3gevolgen2watishetprecies;`

As you can see, there are still `;` in the `classif`-string. Moreover, the `12` should be an `1` and a `2`. At the moment I can't see were the problem is.

Comment: can you give an example how `classif` should look like for user `fxf20`?

Comment: Is `;` counted as one or zero classifications?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein `;` should be counted as zero calssifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude `;` from `classif` and `unique.classif`, you can use:

```
ddply(df, .(user), summarise, links = length(user),
      group = as.factor(substr(user[1], 1, 3)),
      classif = paste(unlist(strsplit(as.character(classifications), ";"))
                      [unlist(strsplit(as.character(classifications), ";")) != ""], 
                      collapse = ","),
      unique.classif = length(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(classifications), ";"))
                                     [unlist(strsplit(as.character(classifications), ";")) != ""]))
)
```

Comment: Thanx for both your solutions. I tested them, but I run into some problems. See my edit of the question.

Comment: @Jaap I cannot reproduce the problem with the example data.

Comment: I changed the example data to a subset which should reproduce the problem.

Comment: With a minor edit, the `classif` part now works as intended. However in counting the `unique.classif` also an empty classification is counted as an unique classification. See for example user `frt02`. How do I solve that?